# my wordpress configuration locally vs live server

Tags: admin, mysql, server, localhost, ftp

I've just got a hosting plan(A free WordPress hosting plan). My website is still in its basic form(the 21 theme from WordPress, and the hello world post). I intend to work locally on my website, then upload it using FTP(in case I didn't know, how I will just use a Migration Plugin). The hosting site provides me with all the info needed(my WordPress admin account, my MySQL database info, my FTP info..).  My question is: while configuring my local setup, should I use some info on my localhost(database name, host, prefix table, database user, WordPress admin info...) as the one provided by the hosting site? Or not.

Comment: Are you intending to transfer your content from your local machine to the hosted site? If so, you'll definitely need some kind of plugin. All of WordPress's post/page content is stored in the database, so uploading your files won't update the hosted site's content.

Comment: now, once you mention it, it makes sence. I think I will use a plugin. But I'm still confused about my setup in localhost, should it be the same as the one in the hosting? Or I just use whatever info I want, and the plugin will take care of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You just need setup couple things for it.

1. Make Database Backup from your localhost
2. Copying all files and folders from your local to the host
3. Adjust wp-config.php following your live site configurations.
4. Import database to live site
5. Replace all local urls with live site have. You can use this query for it

   UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

   UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'oldurl.com','newurl.com');

   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com');

   UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'oldurl.com','newurl.com');

Comment: A lifesaver. Thank you so much for your time.